# Kiosk mode with specific profile Microsoft Edge

Tags: microsoft-edge, fullscreen, kiosk

I would like to setup a Kiosk with Microsoft Edge with the following requirements:

- Opens full screen
- Locked on a domain (no browser interface visible)
- Use a specific profile with same localStorage & cookies.

After some hours of searches, I only found this command line possibility:

```
msedge.exe --kiosk www.contoso.com --edge-kiosk-type=fullscreen
```

This satisfies the two first requirements (full screen, domain locked), but Edge always  open like if in private or with a new profile: I have to signIn again on my application each time.

Is there any way to satisfies the third requirement?

I have also tried to add the following command line arg (with my profile name instead of course):

```
--profile-directory="Profile name"
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Could you open the page, log in, then close the page. Then instead of opening a page in Kiosk mode, use the [Restore on startup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#restoreonstartup) to restaure the previous session? More [info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-configure-kiosk-mode). Also note I'd block all other sites with Family Safety settings or such, because people could find ways (like a Twitter link) to get out this site...

Comment: Can you explain how to set up policies for Edge on win11? Lots of ms docs looks obsolete. I have also tried to set up reopening last tabs on settings, but this does not restore the fullscreen state.

Comment: Sorry but I can't help you more on this subject; I don't know, you may keep on searching the Net or wait for someone who knows?